# I want to change cell reference in the formula with reference to value in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

In sheet 1, on A1 i have a dropdown list of sheet names.

In sheet 1, on cell A2 the value is fetched from Sheet2!A1 and on cell A3 the value is fetched from Sheet2!A2.

There are 100s of rows of data and worksheets.

I want that if i have to see values from same cell reference but of Sheet3 or Sheet 4 then i put formula on Cell A2 such that that formula fetches the sheet name reference from value on cell A1 and the same formula on A2 should be copiable on cell A3 (cell reference of Sheet3 and Sheet4 should change as i copy down the formula from A2 to A3 , A4 and so on.)

Comment: My guess is you need INDIRECT.

Comment: @BigBen yes i tried it but it works for one cell but didnt get copied to next cell with changing range similar to normal copy of formula because everything becomes text

Comment: It might help to provide some sample data and the exact formula you're trying ([edit] into your question).